# Is it possible to get Free/Total/Max memory like Tomcat Manager tell with JMX?

Tags: tomcat, memory, monitoring, jmx

With tomcat 5/6 and JMX enabled, it is possible to get how many free memory is available for monitoring propurses ?

I revised Template_Tomcat from zapcat template, but I didn't see any parameter which could be identified with free/total/max memory . There is parameters related with GC, and heap memory, but I'm really lost with this issue.

I didn't find any reply here or google, maybe I don't understand something which have to be obvious :(

Thank you very much !

Comment: what do you mean by "memory for monitoring propurses" ?

Comment: archiving values in an database and can generate graphs from these values. We have zabbix for monitoring. My english is not good ;)

Answer (score 0):

I realize I am quite late to answer this, but I think you want to get the information from the MBean called Memory. See [this section of Tomcat Monitoring FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Monitoring#Heap_and_other_Memory_Information).

In Zabbix template configuration, you set up items with these keys:

```
jmx[java.lang:type=Memory][HeapMemoryUsage].committed
jmx[java.lang:type=Memory][HeapMemoryUsage].used
jmx[java.lang:type=Memory][HeapMemoryUsage].max
```

If you use ZapCat deployed in Tomcat, you can see the list accessing the MBeans List page generated by ZapCat (something like: `http://localhost:8180/zapcat-1.2/mbeans.jsp`), it lists the available MBeans and attributes.

Note that if you were using JBoss instead, you could use these values (from the MBean named ServerInfo):

```
jmx[jboss.system:type=ServerInfo][MaxMemory]
jmx[jboss.system:type=ServerInfo][TotalMemory]
jmx[jboss.system:type=ServerInfo][FreeMemory]
```

At any rate though, you may want to install `zabbix-agent` in the machine being monitored, so you can monitor CPU, Memory and everything. You would have to set up another host in Zabbix, though.

Hope it helps!

Comment: But that metric is from jboss, I was searching at tomcat level

Thank you, I didn't see your answer until now :)

Comment: @i5513 You're absolutely right, I'm going to see if I discover what would be the proper values for a Tomcat deploy. Maybe `jmx[java.lang:type=Memory][HeapMemoryUsage].used` would work for the used memory?

Comment: @i5513 I've updated with what should be the proper values and a link to the docs. ;)

Comment: Thank you again @elias, so it is not possible to get total / max and free values, only currently /  max heap memory is used.

Comment: @i5513 yeah, if you want to know about the system memory I think you want to install the zabbix-agent.

Comment: Thanks @elias, Yes, with userparam scripts I could be able to obtain that info, I was searching on jmx, but I will have to use a workaround. Thank you again